# Documents Links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a user that wants to add links to a document that would show in the document library below the document.  For example

Document 1
    Link 1
    Link 2
    Link 3
Document 2
    Link 1

Is this possible?  The documents have already been grouped once, but they are not wanting a second grouping, but want the links to attach only to the one document.

Comment: Welcome to the SP.SE community! Can you give some more specifics about the environment? Like which version of SharePoint and what exactly the client wants to accomplish with this system? You can add links as items to a library, but I'm not sure I understand what they are trying to do with them.